# How can I preload img and css?

Tags: css, preload

I try to improve loading times of my web site. As far as I can see preload can be used to load resources like this.:

```
<link rel="preload" href="image.png" as="image">
<link rel="preload" href="examplefile.css" as="style">
```

However, what I don't understand how I can make style and image available in my html code. Do I just have to add it as usual after preloading?

```
<img src="image.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="examplefile.css" >
```

Comment: `preload` is for items that you know will be needed later, not for things you need now. It's also advisory in that the browser is free to ignore it if it wishes. Basically it says, "Hey, browser, you should cache these things. We're not going to use them right now, but we'll be using them a lot later so it would probably be a good idea to fetch them since you're not doing anything else."